# Comparison of (1, 2, 3 nodes) clusters in redshift and csv files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

**While comparing (1 node, 2 node, 3 node) clusters...how to findout which cluster is best in performance?**

In your point of view which cluster is the best in performance

[**How to copy a CSV file from S3 into redshift and specify where i have commited mistake?**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSLVn.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You appear to be asking two questions here: One on performance and one regarding a loading error. Please ask these as two separate questions so that you can receive better answers. Also, please note that opinion-based questions are not well-suited to StackOverflow since there would be many different answers depending upon your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to determine the setup that provides the best performance is to **perform your own tests**. For example, try loading data and runnign queries with different numbers and sizes of nodes. This way, you will have results that are accurate based upon your own particular data and that way that it is stored in Amazon Redshift.

When **loading data** into Redshift, the load will run better when you have more nodes because it is performed in parallel across all nodes.

In general, **more nodes will always give better performance** because each node adds additional storage and compute. However, you will have to **trade-off performance against cost**.